# Скрипт для галереи

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Допустим, картинки разделены на категории: зима, деревья, люди и т.д. Страница разделена на 2 части - в одной картинки небольшого размера, скажем 150х150, в другой - список категорий.  После загрузки страницы картинки отображаются все. При клике на категорию картинки отфильтровываются - остаются только относящиеся к данной тематике.

Нужно сделать красиво, чтобы картинки плавно убирались, появлялись, двигались. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти готовый скрипт или пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут описан весь процесс создания галлереи с фильтром и анимацией:
[Create a Filterable Portfolio Powered by jQuery](http://mazeofminds.com/533/filterable-portfolio-powered-by-jquery/).

Туда же: [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

То же можно сделать и самому, да еще и красивее - с разными размерами картинок, если разобраться с плагином [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Спасибо! Отлично подходит.

Comment: Замечательно! :)